# Display upcoming birthday of user

Tags: php, mysql

I am making birthday management..where if today is the birthday that should display first. if today there is no birthday then the next coming birthday should be displayed. what will be the query and in admin panel?

I have a table with 4 fields:

- id
- name of user
- birthday date('2013-06-13')
- description

I have no idea how to make the query in mysql...

Comment: I manage to have a birthday without an application.

Comment: Have you tried this yourself, or done any research? SO isn't here to just do things for you

Comment: do some more research and come back when you have something more concrete. It' the best way. Good luck.

Comment: `I have no idea`: with only that info, so do I....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
     select id , name , birthday_column
     from users
     where MONTH(birthday_column) = MONTH(NOW())
     AND   DAY(birthday_column)   = DAY(NOW())
     ORDER BY birthday_column
```

this will select those dates who have same month and same day as today. next year will also select same month and same day and so on every year

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT birthday_date_field 
FROM users_table
WHERE birthday_date >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY birthday_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```